# Assistance swapping a grammar to LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar

I have the following grammar

```
S -> E | S A | A
E -> if (C) {S} | if (C) {S} else {S}
A -> V := T;
T -> a | b
V -> x | y
C -> V O T | T O V | V O V | T O T
O -> < | >
```

From this, am I correct in saying this grammar is not LL(1) because for Rule E, "if (C) {S}" can be left-factored out and rule S has a left recursion?

What would be the correct way to fix this?
I was thinking something like:

```
S -> P
P -> ER | AR
R -> AR | ε
E -> if (C) {S} B
B -> else {S}
A -> V := T;
T -> a | b
V -> x | y
C -> V O T | T O V | V O V | T O T
O -> < | >
```

Comment: This question is better suited to [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

### Left-factoring `E`

You propose to factor

```
E -> if (C) {S} | if (C) {S} else {S}
```

into

```
E -> if (C) {S} B
B -> else {S}
```

Now, it's no longer possible to parse the `if (C) {S}` form, since `B` can't be empty. So, this transformation is **not correct**.

Instead, consider this:

```
B -> else {S} | ε
```

### Removing direct left recursion in `S`

You propose to replace

```
S -> E | S A | A
```

by

```
S -> P
P -> ER | AR
R -> AR | ε
```

While this is a **correct** transformation, the following would also be sufficient:

```
S -> ER | AR
R -> AR | ε
```